# Slow VBA when selecting visible pivot items from another table

Tags: vba, performance, filter, olap, visible

I have **OLAP** pivot tables with more than 10000 pivot items. When filtering this pivot table based on another table, it takes minutes, even after manual calculation.
Can someone help me optimize this?

```
Sub Pivot_Filter()

' Save the current state of Excel settings.
  screenUpdateState = Application.ScreenUpdating
  statusBarState = Application.DisplayStatusBar
  calcState = Application.Calculation
  eventsState = Application.EnableEvents
   ' Note: this is a sheet-level setting.
  displayPageBreakState = ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks

 ' Turn off Excel functionality to improve performance.
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
  Application.EnableEvents = False
 ' Note: this is a sheet-level setting.
  ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

   Dim PI As PivotItem

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable8").PivotFields("nomes")
   ManualUpdate = True
  .ClearAllFilters

    For Each PI In .PivotItems
        PI.Visible = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("a2:a19"), PI.Name) > 0
    Next PI
    ManualUpdate = False
End With

' Restore Excel settings to original state.
 Application.ScreenUpdating = screenUpdateState
 Application.DisplayStatusBar = statusBarState
 Application.Calculation = calcState
 Application.EnableEvents = eventsState
' Note: this is a sheet-level setting
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = displayPageBreaksState

End Sub
```

Comment: Difficult to help without the data required to reproduce the issue.

Comment: My first guess would be that `WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("a2:a19"), PI.Name)` is the culprit. You're reading the same range A2:A19 from Excel 10000 times. Just read it once, store it in an array, and search that array for `PI.Name`.